# Custom loader before HtmlWebpackPlugin causes "Unexpected token" error

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on making a custom loader that's going to take the HTML template specified for HtmlWebpackPlugin, perform some alterations, and then pass it along.

To start, I made a loader that echos what it is given:

```
//loader.js

module.exports = function(fileContent){
  return fileContent
}
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
  File was processed with these loaders:
   * ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js
   * ./loader.js
```

The HTML file is just for testing, it looks like this:

```
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why such an error would happen. I looked at the source code for the HtmlWebpackPlugin and tried logging what it receives to the console, but it's the exact same as what I return in `loader.js`.

I tried giving it a plain string to see what would happen, like this:

```
//loader.js

module.exports = function(fileContent){
  return "test"
}
```

But then it tells me:

```
HtmlWebpackPlugin
ReferenceError: test is not defined
 - loader.js:1 eval
//...and so on
```

Huh? So I guess it's trying to evaluate what I give it? I'm not sure what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the [loader code](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/lib/loader.js) for HtmlWebpackPlugin:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that in my case, a better approach would just be to load the template as a Javascript module from a file.

```
//webpack.config.js

new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: "./src/customLoader.js",
  filename: name + ".html",
  chunks: [name],
})
```

```
//customLoader.js

module.exports = (htmlFile) => {
  //...do stuff
  return modifiedHtmlFile;
};
```